# How to add a "get permalink" button to post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am working in this spanish comic website: www.tuscomics.com

And I would like some help to display a button above every post that will copy to clipboard or displays the permalink of the post, so it's easy for people to link their friends to a post they like.

I have been searching for a plugin with no luck.

Thank you very much!

Nathalie.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_post_permalink()` to return the link, then output it inside of a button as @Ljubisa suggested.

So long as it's used inside of the 'The Loop', you don't need to supply an ID.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_excerpt();?>

<?php echo "<form action='";
     echo the_permalink();
     echo "' method='get'>";?>
<button>Read More..</button>
```

So first part is your article, second part is the `button` form, you need it in the form otherwise it will give W3 error you can't have it with out form.

I hope that helps you.